# Local Notification trigger not working (ionic 3)

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed the plugin without any problems and I tested and nothing happened

```
let hr = 19;
let mn = 25;
let ss=1;

this.localNotifications.schedule(
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Asthma app",
    text: "c’est le temps d’évaluer le contrôle de votre asthme",
    sound: this.platform.is('android') ? 'file://sound.mp3' :'file://beep.caf',
    icon: 'assets/imgs/supplies.png',
    every: { hour: hr, minute: mn ,second : ss} 
});
```

Help me please.

Comment: How do you test it? On real android?

Comment: I tested with an Android device